# Looping through a block in a specific number of times that exists in django model

Tags: python, django

I have models "Event", "Ticket" and "Order". When someone orders for a Ticket(s) for a specific event, it is saved in order. In Order model/table, I have amount and other fields, then, quantity(to know the quantity the person actually selected for ticket class A and ticket class B for a particular event. After ordering, I want to display Ticket class A and Ticket class B the number of times(according to the quantity the user chose for each of them) so they can print. I have tried many things for hours and looping through an int(which is not possible in django) Any way around this? Snippet below

## Models

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    # if quantity is null, the number of available tickets is unlimited
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    # number of tickets that can be bought at once, null = unlimited
    quantity_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    sales_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sales_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, blank=True)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    transactionID = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Order date'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

## Views

```
ticketOrder = Order.objects.filter(transactionID=transactionID)
ticketList=[]
ticketClass=[]
for each_ticket_print in ticketOrder:
    ticketClass = each_ticket_print.ticket.name
    txID = each_ticket_print.transactionID
    ticketList.append(each_ticket_print)
myList = []
mainList = []
counter = 1
myTicketList = []
for x in ticketOrder:
    eventMemo = x.event
    ticketMemo = x.ticket
    z = int(x.quantity)
    for counter in range(counter, z+1):
        myList.append(counter)
        counter += 1
    counter = 1
    mainList.append(myList)
    myList = []
context = { 'myList': myList,
    'mainList': mainList,
    'transactionID': transactionID,
    'ticketMemo': ticketMemo,
    'eventMemo': eventMemo,
    'each_ticket_print': each_ticket_print,
}
return render_to_response(template,context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in the Ticket print template

```
{% for item in mainList %}
    {% for items in item %}
         <p>{{ items }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Displays the below for debugging purpose. Means Ticket A order was 6 quantities and Ticket B 5 quantities

```
# Output of Ticket A
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6

```
# Output of Ticket B
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

Comment: could you post the models? It is not clear where the 'ticket class' is.

Comment: Updated now, with models

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should refactor your code.

- The `Ticket` shouldn't care about maximum available tickets, this is a field for the `Event` model.
- Each `Order` instance should be related to all it's tickets by a OneToMany-relationship (i.e. a ForeignKey to `Order` from `Ticket`)
- If you want to loop over all related tickets to your order, you can then just do `for ticket in self.ticket_set.all():`
- If you want total number of tickets, you *may* save this as a field on the order model, or you can simply use `self.ticket_set.count()`

This exemplifies what I'm suggesting:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    sales_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sales_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, blank=True)
    transactionID = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name='Order date')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def total_amount(self):
        return sum(ticket.amount for ticket in self.ticket_set)

    def ticket_type(self, t):
        return self.ticket_set.filter(type=t)


class Ticket(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices={(('A', 'Main stand'),
                                                    ('B', 'Lower stand'))})
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

Using these models, you can now easily pass the objects you want to your template:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def view_order(request, transactionID):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, transactionID=transactionID)
    class_a = order.ticket_set.filter(type='A')
    class_b = order.ticket_set.filter(type='B')
    context = {'class_a': class_a, 'class_b': class_b, 'id': transactionID}
    return render(request, 'app_name/view_order.html', context)
```

**app_name/view_order.html**

```
Order details for transaction "{{ id }}"
<h3>Class A tickets:
{% for ticket in class_a %}
    {{ ticket.amount }} <!-- Print whatever you'd like here, all Ticket fields are available -->
{% endfor %}

<h3>Class B tickets:
{% for ticket in class_b %}
    {{ ticket.amount }} <!-- Print whatever you'd like here, all Ticket fields are available -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am writing an App that we don't know the amount of tickets and Event may have yet. It may have four! Also, Events should not have "quantity", you can know the quantity for a Ticket class for a particular Event, not the quantity of an Event.

Comment: By quantity I meant available tickets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to rewrite your view in a simpler manner:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def ticket_print(request, transactionID):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(transactionID=transactionID)
    ticket_class = defaultdict(list)
    for order in orders:
        for ticket in range(int(order.ticket.quantity)):
            ticket_class[ticket.name].append(ticket)

    return render_to_response(template,
                              {"tickets": ticket_class}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the templates the tickets should come as a dictionary grouped by ticket class name:

```
{% for ticketclass, ticketlist in tickets.iteritems %}
    {% for ticket in ticketlist %}
        print ticket
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has worked. This is what I did

Views

```
            myList = []
            mainList = []
            counter = 1
            ticketMemo  = ''
            for x in a:
                eventMemo = x.event
                ticketMemo = x.ticket
                z = int(x.quantity)
                for counter in range(counter, z+1):
                    myList.append(ticketMemo)
                    counter += 1
                counter = 1
                mainList.append(myList)
                myList = []
                context = { 
                        'mainList': mainList,
                        'transactionID': transactionID,
                        'ticketMemo': ticketMemo,
                        'eventMemo': eventMemo,
                        'eventLoc':eventLoc,
                        'eventDate':eventDate,
                        'ticketClass': ticketClass,
                          }
                return render_to_response(template,context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
{% for item in mainList %}
    {% for items in item %}
        <div class="print">
            <div class="ticketSmall" style="margin-left: 10%;">
                <div class="ticketType"><h2>{{ items|title }}</h2></div>
                <div class="imgHolder"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ eventMemo.logo }}" width="270" height="300">
                Print this Ticket and come with it to the venue
                </div>
                <div class="ticketInfo"><h2>{{ eventMemo|title }}</h2>
                    <ul>
                            <li>Venue:<b> {{ eventLoc|title }}</b></li>
                            <li>Date: <b>{{ eventDate|date }}</b></li>
                            <li>Time: <b>{{ eventDate|time }}</b></li>
                            <li>Ticket Purchased By: <strong>{{ user.first_name|title }}&nbsp;{{ user.last_name|title }}</strong></li>
                            <li>Ticket Type: <strong>{{ items|title }}</strong></li>
                            <li>Date of Purchase: <strong>{{ now }}</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```